# Spyder IDE editor multiline string query (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I'm trying to make a SQL query that can be used with pandas.read_sql_query.

```
query = '''SELECT var1, var2, var3, var4,
        var5, var6, var7, var8, var9
        FROM table 
        WHERE area='there' '''
```

This works when running in the console, but when I try to execute this in the Spyder editor I see the following:

SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: I'm not sure how this would run in Spyder and not the regular Python interpreter.

Comment: It runs in both, I just tested. You're doing something else in your code. Please include the traceback.

Comment: It runs in the IPython console within Spyder, but not when using 'Run selection or current line' in the Spyder Editor.

Comment: Why would you expect a multi-line string to run correctly when you run a single line? I haven't tried it, but that doesn't sound reasonable.

Comment: Coming from RStudio, I was expecting the entire code chunk to run with the 'Run selection or current line' command, but realize now that you have to highlight all that you want to run. Know of any Python IDEs that have that feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The problem is your trying to run your selected code **line by line** with our *Run selection or current line* functionality. After running the first line in your code, i.e.

```
query = '''SELECT var1, var2, var3, var4,
```

it's clear you'll get

`SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal`

because that line doesn't close the string you started.

*Note*: *Run selection or current line* expects a **complete** Python statement, i.e. something that can be evaluated as it is in Python (e.g. `a = 10`).

Answer (score 1):

In order to write multi line sql query in spyder, please enclose the SQL query within three double quotations i.e. 3 double quotations at the start of the SQL statement and 3 at the end.  I am able to write multi line SQL statements for use with Pandas, in Spyder, using this approach.  for e.g.

""" 
select *
from table_name
where column_name = value
"""

Comment: The code provided by the user is already enclosed in triple quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your quotes around 'there' to be double quotes "there".

Comment: Same thing, works in console but not when run in editor.   query = '''SELECT var1, var2,var3, var4,
  File "<ipython-input-9-4ede1ae4f09b>", line 1
    query = '''SELECT var1, var2,var3, var4,
                                            ^
SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Comment: What if you move the final ''' to its own line?